# How to get rid of white edges in ionic app

Tags: reactjs, ionic-framework, sass

I want to get rid of the white space at the edges.
You can see style properties in the screenshot.

Thats my react code:

```
<IonPage>
  <IonHeader>
  </IonHeader>
  <IonContent fullscreen scrollY={false}>
    <IonGrid>
      <IonRow>
        <IonText>Spiel 1</IonText>
      </IonRow>
      <IonRow>
        <IonText>Spiel 2</IonText>
      </IonRow>
    </IonGrid>
  </IonContent>
</IonPage>
```

[image]

Comment: I was able to get rid of the white space everywhere than on the bottom with these style properties on ion-grid:
margin: -10px -10px 80px -10px;

Answer (score 0):

Was able to get rid of all white edges by changing the css properties of ion-grid to this:

```
ion-grid {
  margin: -10px;
  height: 110%;
};
```